# Nokia Bluetooth headset Bh 503 not recognized

Tags: bluetooth

I bought an Nokia Bluetooth Phone Bh 503. It works just fine with my Android phone, but with Ubuntu it even get recognized. I already paired the Ubuntu with my Android, but with the bluetooth phone it even find it.

What can be the problem?

Already search in Google for answers, but almost always the problem is with bluetooth that doesn't work, but in my case it works, but not with the headset.

Already install almost all packages about bluetooth, like blueman, bluez, gnome-bluetooth, bluetooth, etc.

Comment: I think you are referring to a Nokia Bluetooth headset bh-503, i have same problem with my Ubuntu precise. i'm still looking for solutions but any help is very much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Looks like is a commum problem:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1463610

But some people using it:
http://projectzeorymer.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/ubuntu-how-to-connect-nokia-bh-503-bluetooth-headset-to-your-pc/

Comment: i just connected my bh-503 few days ago with precise, you have to turn-off and turn-on again your headset, when turning on hold the button until the lights turn into blue and green, scan the device. that works for me. but the audio is very awful. it works great with lucid.

Comment: Hmm, I will try again them. I thought it could be an problem when bluetooth from my laptop, Dell 15R. 

Maybe it doesn't support something. Maybe I will try with and external bluetooth adapter too.

About the audio, when I was searching for solutions, I saw many people with same problem and fix it with some packages that I don't remember very well now.

Comment: Work! Thanks Eric!
The audio isn't perfect too, I will try to fix it. 

I had to turn on the "configure new device" on PC. Then, I just turn On the HeadeSet, wait sometime, Turn it Off and when turn it on again, keep pressing the button, work perfectly.

Comment: Found the solution (at least for me) Erick, look at that:
http://projectzeorymer.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/ubuntu-how-to-connect-nokia-bh-503-bluetooth-headset-to-your-pc/

Comment: Perhaps related to this?
[#508522](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/508522)

Comment: @erickjohncuevas Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: It's just working, i Don't have sure if it's because the packages or not.

Comment: @JorgeCastro sorry i wasn't able to reply immediately, do i have to? coz it seems their is already an answer below but i will do it anyway if in-case it is redundant please delete the answer.

Answer (score 4):

*(comment to answer solved issue)*

- I just connected my bh-503 few days ago with precise, you have to turn-off and turn-on again your headset, when turning on hold the button until the lights turn into blue and green, scan the device. that works for me. but the audio is very awful. it works great with lucid. – erickjohncuevas Jan 23 at 10:25
- It's just working, I Don't have sure if it's because the packages or not. – euDennis Mar 9 at 0:14

Answer (score 1):

I have the same headsets and works for me in a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04, I'll tell you what I did:

1. Install Blueman and open it.
2. Open Blueman, put the headset in pairing mode (when turning on, press the power button until you see a blue light blinking)
3. Hit "Search" In Blueman. You'll see the headset there.
4. Right click on the headset, "add", then "trust", then "Pair". Immediately after that, "Connect to" - and choose the option "Audio Sink".
5. If the headset is connected, will beep twice and the light will change to green. Enjoy.

If you don't have sound after that, follow this steps:

1) Stop, and if possible, close everything that is playing audio.

2) Go to Blueman, right click in the headset, and check that the headset is not connected to headset service and audio sink at the same time. If is the case, disconnect it from headset service only.

3) Try again, if doesn't' work, disconnect it from audio sink as well, and reconnect, or remove it and repeat the procedure again. Is a bit of a headache in the beginning, but the headset works fine. Also, make sure to set up the headset before starting to play music, otherwise you most likely will have issues.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i just connected my bh-503 few days ago with precise, you have to turn-off and turn-on again your headset, when turning on hold the button until the lights turn into blue and green, scan the device. that works for me. but the audio is very awful. it works great with lucid. – erickjohncuevas Jan 23 at 10:25

Comment: After the headset is connected, you have to change an option in sound config, something about use the A2P, I don't remember now... but you have to do that only in the first time you connect.

Comment: @Adryn says: "The awful sound can be solve by changing the mode to High Fidelity Playback(A2DP) at sound setting there.

step: -go to sound setting
-click Headset Nokia BH-503
-change the mode to High Fidelity Playback(A2DP)"

Answer (score -1):

The awful sound can be solve by changing the mode to High Fidelity Playback(A2DP) at sound setting there.

step:

- go to sound setting
- click Headset Nokia BH-503
- change the mode to High Fidelity Playback(A2DP)

Then viola! problem solve!